# Function SUMIFS in array formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I can't figure out how to make an array formula with a SUMIFS function.
I want my results from SUMIFS to be ponderated by a ratio.
See atatched example file.

Have a nice week-end!
Nicolas

Here follow a link to the example: [enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoGgtER6EbVQhE4kgxr_Z-YsyFMA)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an array in SUMIFS.

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(F4:F16,G4:G16,(C4:C16=K4)*(D4:D16=K5))
```

[image]